# how can I destroy a record without an ID column in ruby ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a table without an ID column. When I try to delete from it using ActiveRecord the generated SQL is `DELETE FROM table_name WHERE ID=NULL`, which obviously doesn't work. Is there any way to delete from the table using ActiveRecord, or at least run a raw SQL delete query with placeholders (so it's not vulnerable to SQL injection)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Have you tried using ActiveRecord's delete_all method? Here's an excerpt in a sandbox of mine:

```
>> customer = Customer.new(:login => 'foo')
=> #<Customer id: nil, status: 0, name: nil, login: "foo", password: nil, salt: nil, api_key: nil, address: nil, town: nil, state: nil, country: "USA", zipcode: nil, balance: #<BigDecimal:1032669b0,'0.0',9(18)>, discount: 0, last_four_cc: nil, auto_renew: false, contact_name: nil, contact_email: nil, domain: "anon.limelock.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> customer.save
=> true
>> Customer.all.count
=> 4
>> Customer.delete_all(:login => 'foo')
=> 1
>> Customer.all.count
=> 3
```

The generated SQL is `` DELETE FROM `customers` WHERE (`customers`.`login` = 'foo') ``

Check out the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001789)

Comment: This is the way to go. I was going to answer this.

Comment: This doesn't work in all cases. I have a model Game and a model AppVersion. Game has_many :app_versions.
`Game.first.app_versions.delete_all` produces `DELETE FROM 'app_versions' WHERE 'app_versions'.'' = NULL`, which is an error.

Comment: When you use this on a relation, Rails 4.2 says that on `.delete_all` method, there are only two options to pass: `:nullify` which set null on the foreing_keys and `:delete_all` which actually removes those objects. And the default value is `:nullify`.

Comment: The most up-to-date way of doing this is with `Customer.where(login: "foo").delete_all`.
```

Answer (score 11):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('DELETE FROM table_name WHERE ...')
```

I think you need to have a unique id column for ActiveRecord to function right, but I'm not 100% sure.