# How do you delete an ActiveRecord object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

How do you delete an ActiveRecord object?

I looked at [Active Record Querying](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) and it does not have anything on deleting that I can see.

1. Delete by `id`,
2. Delete the current object like: `user.remove`,
3. Can you delete based on a `where` clause?

Answer (score 644, accepted):

It's `destroy` and `destroy_all` methods, like

```
user.destroy
User.find(15).destroy
User.destroy(15)
User.where(age: 20).destroy_all
User.destroy_all(age: 20)
```

Alternatively you can use `delete` and `delete_all` which won't enforce `:before_destroy` and `:after_destroy` callbacks or any dependent association options.

> `User.delete_all(condition: 'value')` will allow you to delete records
>   without a primary key

**Note**: from @hammady's comment, `user.destroy` won't work if User model has no primary key.

**Note 2**: From @pavel-chuchuva's comment, `destroy_all` with conditions and `delete_all` with conditions has been deprecated in Rails 5.1 - see guides.rubyonrails.org/5_1_release_notes.html

Comment: It would be nice if you could include @hammady's comment in your answer. Struggled to find out why I couldn't destroy my model object...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978219/how-can-i-destroy-a-record-without-an-id-column-in-ruby-activerecord

Comment: Why it only updates deleted_at column data in my database? How can I delete the whole row of data?

Comment: destroy_all with conditions and delete_all with conditions has been deprecated in Rails 5.1 - see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/5_1_release_notes.html

Comment: this `User.find_by(username:"bob")`  is good to identify the record to destroy or delete, too.

Comment: `User.find(15).destroy` doesn't work if `User.find(15)` returned `nil`.

Comment: @TommyQu Are you using https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia or acts_as_paranoid? These gems do a soft-delete by setting `deleted_at` instead of removing the record completely. To hard-delete, you need to call `really_destroy!` (or whatever the library uses).

Comment: In current Rails: replace `destroy_all condition` (with condition arguments) by  `destroy_by condition` (in addtion to Note 2)

Answer (score 67):

There is `delete`, `delete_all`, `destroy`, and `destroy_all`.

The docs are: [older docs](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M000341) and [Rails 3.0.0 docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-delete)

`delete` doesn't instantiate the objects, while `destroy` does.  In general, `delete` is faster than `destroy`.

Comment: `delete` is faster but bypasses the callbacks you might have defined on the model

Answer (score 52):

1. `User.destroy`

`User.destroy(1)` will delete user with `id == 1` and `:before_destroy` and `:after_destroy` callbacks occur. For example if you have associated records

```
has_many :addresses, :dependent => :destroy
```

After user is destroyed his addresses will be destroyed too.
If you use delete action instead, callbacks will not occur.

2. `User.destroy`, `User.delete`
3. `User.destroy_all(<conditions>)` or `User.delete_all(<conditions>)`

**Notice**: User is a class and user is an instance object

Comment: BEWARE: `User.destroy_all()` runs callbacks, so before it deletes anything, it loads records. It's two SQL statements not one. Aside from the performance implications, this has concurrency implications too. The safer call skips callbacks; `User.delete_all()` will issue just a single `DELETE FROM...` command.

Comment: destroy_all with conditions has been deprecated in Rails 5.1 - see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/5_1_release_notes.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Rails 5 and above, the following solution will work.

```
#delete based on id
user_id = 50
User.find(id: user_id).delete_all

#delete based on condition
threshold_age = 20
User.where(age: threshold_age).delete_all
```

https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActiveRecord%2FNullRelation:delete_all

Answer (score -2):

Deleting a row from a particular table or a record set from a table is pretty simple, from your console all you need to do is grab the record set by its Id then delete or destroy it.

Comment: Telling is nice but showing is better, and many other answers that have been here for a decade show how to do this. I suggest upvoting one of those instead of adding a vague additional answer.