# Trying to delete from array - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an array of a user's favourite_guidelines.  In my console it looks like this:

```
fg=User.first.favourite_guidelines
  User Load (73.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
  FavouriteGuideline Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "favourite_guidelines".* FROM "favourite_guidelines" WHERE "favourite_guidelines"."user_id" = 11
 => [#<FavouriteGuideline id: 16, guideline_id: 24, user_id: 11, created_at: "2013-02-17 01:03:19", updated_at: "2013-02-17 01:03:19">, #<FavouriteGuideline id: 18, guideline_id: 23, user_id: 11, created_at: "2013-02-17 11:40:27", updated_at: "2013-02-17 11:40:27">]
```

So it contains two guidelines.  I would like to be able to delete a value of a certain guideline_id so that the user's favourite guidelines would have that favourite removed.  At the moment I have:

```
User.first,favourite_guidelines.delete_if{|favourite| favourite["guideline_id"] == 24}
```

That gives me:

```
.9.3p194 :066 > User.first.favourite_guidelines.delete_if{|favourite| favourite["guideline_id"] == 24}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
  FavouriteGuideline Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "favourite_guidelines".* FROM "favourite_guidelines" WHERE "favourite_guidelines"."user_id" = 11
 => [#<FavouriteGuideline id: 18, guideline_id: 23, user_id: 11, created_at: "2013-02-17 11:40:27", updated_at: "2013-02-17 11:40:27">]'
```

So it looks like it is deleteing it but it's obviously not saving because then if I do:

```
    1.9.3p194 :067 > User.first.favourite_guidelines
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
  FavouriteGuideline Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "favourite_guidelines".* FROM "favourite_guidelines" WHERE "favourite_guidelines"."user_id" = 11
 => [#<FavouriteGuideline id: 16, guideline_id: 24, user_id: 11, created_at: "2013-02-17 01:03:19", updated_at: "2013-02-17 01:03:19">, #<FavouriteGuideline id: 18, guideline_id: 23, user_id: 11, created_at: "2013-02-17 11:40:27", updated_at: "2013-02-17 11:40:27">]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are deleting from array not from table..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   User.first.favourite_guidelines.destroy( :guideline_id => 24)
```

Or

```
  User.first.favourite_guidelines.where( :guideline_id => 24).destroy_all
```

Answer (score 1):

`delete_if` works on Array of returned records but not on database. Try:

```
User.first.favourite_guidelines.where(guideline_id: 24).destroy_all
```

PS. Also you could look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177686/how-do-you-delete-in-active-record)

Comment: yes - that's it!  Is there a way to pass something other than the id though (i.e. I want to pass the guideline_id but this takes the favourite_guideline_id)

Comment: Yes. See the link added. You can `destroy_all(some_field: some_value)`

Comment: Yes!!!  I love you.  Thank you.  User.first.favourite_guidelines.where(:guideline_id => 24).destroy_all

Comment: This is wrong. It will delete favourite_guideline with id 24 not with guide_line_id 24