# How to delete built resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

My question is how to delete built resource with iteration?
Lets say i have user with many BUILT (not yet in the database) posts.
How can i delete specific posts?
I tried this aproach but nope:

```
@user.posts.each {|post| post.delete if post.content.nil? }
```

Of course it goes through posts, execute 'delete' method, but all the posts are where they were at the beginning...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are working with `built` objects that are not been committed to the database, the regular methods `destroy`, `delete` on the `Post` objects will not work. You will have to deal with the `@user.posts` collection directly.

I usually use this approach:

```
@user.posts.each { |post| @user.posts.destroy(post) if post.content.nil? }
```

It's working fine from the rails console.

#### About `delete_all` and `destroy_all` with conditions

These two methods would come in handy, but they are part of the `ActiveRecord::Relation` domain. The `@user.posts` collection is an association and not a relation, so it only exposes the `delete_all` method with no conditions.

If you want to use them, you should try something like this:

```
 Post.delete_all(user_id: @user, content: nil)
```

Comment: Delete is a valid option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177686/how-do-you-delete-in-active-record

Comment: Try it in your console. `question = Question.new(title: 'blah'); question.destroy; question` See what you will find.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a rails-console-tested solution.

Comment: I don't know what's OP's real question. Honestly it looks hacky if the problem need to be solved like this :)

Comment: this actually works! but it seems this solution gonna need much 'energy', am i wrong?

Comment: Why much energy? It's doing just what you need in the most direct way. You are using `build` and `destroy`, nothing more nothing less.

Comment: well im concerned about loading @user every time i want to destroy a post...(inside the block i mean)

Comment: You have already loaded that object, so it's fine to call it inside the block. If you're not convinced, try the code in the rails console, so you can see what sql calls are made and when.

Answer (score 2):

Use `delete_all` with a criteria

```
@user.posts.delete_all("content IS NULL")
```

[See here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/delete_all) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reset` method. It unloads the association. [Method API here](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy/reset)

This will remove all `built` objects that are not been committed to the database:

```
@user.posts.reset
```