# delete a row of signed_in user of a particular table in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On the "settings" page I have some controls and data on it, and for updating the data, first I want to delete a row of signed_in user of a particular table i.e "Communication" and after that insert new row in the "Communication" table. For deleting row the code is below:

```
  def create
  Communication.delete_all(:UserID => current_user.id)
  render 'new'
  end
```

In the above code, after delete row I render it to "new" of "settings" page and below is the code of new.html.erb of "settings" page:

```
<%= form_for :settings,:url => {:action => :create} do |f| %>
     <table>
        <% @user_communication.each do |user_com| %>
        <tr style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">
             <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
                Phone:
             </td>
             <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
                <% if user_com.CommunicationMode.to_s == "Phone" %>
                <%= text_field_tag :phone, user_com.CommunicationDetail, placeholder: 'Phone' %>
                <% else %>
                <%= text_field :phone, :placeholder => "Phone" %>
                <% end %>
             </td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
    </table>
<% end %>
```

And below is the route of "settings" page:

```
  match '/setting', to: 'setting#create', via: "get"
```

But when I click on "Update" button I gave me error below:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/settings/create"
```

And below is rake routes:

```
settings_create_path    GET     /settings/create(.:format)  settings#create
settings_destroy_path   GET     /settings/destroy(.:format)     settings#destroy
settings_new_path   GET     /settings/new(.:format)     settings#new
educations_create_path  GET     /educations/create(.:format)    educations#create
educations_destroy_path     GET     /educations/destroy(.:format)   educations#destroy
professions_create_path     GET     /professions/create(.:format)   professions#create
professions_destroy_path    GET     /professions/destroy(.:format)  professions#destroy
communications_create_path  GET     /communications/create(.:format)    communications#create
communications_destroy_path     GET     /communications/destroy(.:format)   communications#destroy
availabilities_create_path  GET     /availabilities/create(.:format)    availabilities#create
availabilities_destroy_path     GET     /availabilities/destroy(.:format)   availabilities#destroy
users_path  GET     /users(.:format)    users#index
    POST    /users(.:format)    users#create
new_user_path   GET     /users/new(.:format)    users#new
edit_user_path  GET     /users/:id/edit(.:format)   users#edit
user_path   GET     /users/:id(.:format)    users#show
    PATCH   /users/:id(.:format)    users#update
    PUT     /users/:id(.:format)    users#update
    DELETE  /users/:id(.:format)    users#destroy
sessions_path   POST    /sessions(.:format)     sessions#create
new_session_path    GET     /sessions/new(.:format)     sessions#new
session_path    DELETE  /sessions/:id(.:format)     sessions#destroy
availabilities_path     POST    /availabilities(.:format)   availabilities#create
availability_path   DELETE  /availabilities/:id(.:format)   availabilities#destroy
communications_path     POST    /communications(.:format)   communications#create
communication_path  DELETE  /communications/:id(.:format)   communications#destroy
professions_path    POST    /professions(.:format)  professions#create
profession_path     DELETE  /professions/:id(.:format)  professions#destroy
educations_path     POST    /educations(.:format)   educations#create
education_path  DELETE  /educations/:id(.:format)   educations#destroy
settings_path   POST    /settings(.:format)     settings#create
new_setting_path    GET     /settings/new(.:format)     settings#new
root_path   GET     /   static_pages#home
signup_path     GET     /signup(.:format)   users#new
signin_path     GET     /signin(.:format)   sessions#new
signout_path    DELETE  /signout(.:format)  sessions#destroy
default_path    GET     /default(.:format)  static_pages#default
    GET     /availabilities(.:format)   availabilities#new
    GET     /communications(.:format)   communications#new
    GET     /professions(.:format)  professions#new
    GET     /educations(.:format)   educations#new
    GET     /settings(.:format)     settings#new
```

So what should I do. kindly help me, waiting for your reply. Thanks

Comment: Remove via:get in your route

Comment: Via ? That's your problem staring at you right there

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have a wrong route.

Why not to just use standard `resources :settings, only: :create`?

Answer (score 0):

**delete**

If you want to delete "a" (singular) row from the `Communication` model, you need to stay away from [`delete_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/delete_all/class). You just should use [`.destroy`](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveRecord/Base/destroy/class) or [`.delete`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/delete/class) instead:

```
 communications = current_user.communications
 communications.destroy([id here])
```

[How do you delete an ActiveRecord object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177686/how-do-you-delete-in-active-record)

---

**Route**

Your error basically means you've not got a route set up correctly (you're sending a `POST` request to a `GET` route):

```
#your resources (controllers) should be plural
resources :settings, only: [:new, :create]
```

Comment: But I think ".destroy" and ".delete" delete all data from the particular table i.e "Communication" and the main table i.e user.

Comment: `delete` & `destroy` are the same as `destroy_all` except they only remove single entries. You mentioned you wanted to get rid of one record, which means `destroy_all` would be highly inefficient

Comment: But after using this "resources :settings, only: [:new, :create]" the routing error still come

Comment: Yep because your controller needs to be called `SettingsController` (yours is `SettingController`