# How to destroy an ActiveRecord relation in Rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a way to do the following?:

```
>items=Item.where('location_id=?',8)
>items.count # 12; now delete all of them
>items.destroy
```

I know I could do `Item.destroy_all('location_id=?',8)` but I'd rather do a count to check my work before a destructive operation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you delete in active record?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177686/how-do-you-delete-in-active-record)

Comment: @BradWerth not a dupe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it via `ActiveRecord::Relation#destroy_all` [method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy_all):

```
items.destroy_all
```

or

```
Item.destroy_all(location_id: 8)
```

each record will be destroyed one by one. If you want to delete it quickly, without additional checking, use [`delete_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/delete_all) instead:

```
items.delete_all
# or
Item.delete_all(location_id: 8)
```

Comment: so destroy_all is too risky. I want to do a where, verify, and then act upon the ActiveRecord relation.

Comment: verify the count and act upon the relation. Like if you are using `rails c` on production. destroy_all would take the condition and I'd rather just work upon the relation.

Comment: @timpone this will work as requested... You do not need a condition for the instance method. Did you even try it?

Comment: yeah, you're right, I had an issue with something in my history. my fault. thx for help

Answer (score 2):

The method is called [`#destroy_all`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-destroy_all).

```
items.destroy_all
```

Comment: so I want to do a find first, verify via count, and then destroy all of them; destroy_all takes a condition and then destroys them

Comment: @timpone this will work as requested... You do not need a condition for the instance method. Did you even try it?