# How to destroy/delete a Rails Active Record without an id column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, destroy

Is there a way to destroy Rails Active Record entries in a table *without* an `id` column?
I know there are a few ways to destroy Active Records with `ids`, like these:

```rb
User.destroy(1)
User.first.destroy
```

However, I cannot seem to find a way to do so without an `id`. I've checked the suggestions in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978219/how-can-i-destroy-a-record-without-an-id-column-in-ruby-activerecord) but to no avail.
Ideally, what I have in mind is something like this:

```rb
User.where(name: "Dummy").destroy
# Returns this:
# ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1))
```

I know that it's generally discouraged to create tables in Rails without an `id` column. While I'd like to rid of it for this particular table if possible, I am willing to make the column if it turns out there are no workarounds. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side note...When you run a query and you are expecting a single record you can call `.first` on the relation to grab it. @Marek's answer is what you are looking for here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason `User.where(name: 'Dummy').destroy` doesn't work is `User.where(name: 'Dummy')` is a relation, not a single record. If you want, for example, to destroy all the records with `name` equal to `'Dummy'`, you can use `destroy_all`:

```
User.where(name: 'Dummy').destroy_all
```

Comment: Or `User.find_by(name: 'Dummy').destroy`. Find_by returns a single record

Comment: What about, say, `User.find_by(name: 'Dummy').to_a`?

Comment: @Marek Lipka Thank you! For some reason, in my case, `User.where(name: 'Dummy').destroy_all` and `User.find_by(name: 'Dummy').destroy` both returned this error: `PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"`

However, this worked: `User.where(name: 'Dummy').delete_all`

Comment: @MarekLipka I get the `NoMethodError (undefined method 'to_a')` when I tried `to_a`. Not sure why `delete_all` works while `destroy_all` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to remove column, you can use

```
User.find_by_name(name: "dummy").destroy
```

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment to the question/other answer.